# Restart current Activity to change application wide theme

Tags: android, android-activity, android-theme

From what I have researched, Android does not have a practical way to change overall application themes.

My application is somewhat simple, Activity wise, and I think this method of handling theme changes is safe.

I want to know if the method below is a safe, or is this a hack job and there are better ways to implement application wide themes?

Notes:

`MainActivtiy.java` is the entry point and only Activity besides the `SettingsActivty.java`

`SettingsActivity.java` extends the `PreferenceActivty` to display a typical preference screen. The theme setting is stored in the default shared preference identified by `R.string.colorThemeListPrefStr` where the `android:entryValues` are {"0", "1"}

`Settings.java` is just a class for static variables that are safe while the application is in memory, anything that needs to be saved between session is saved to shared preferences during `onPause()`.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        // get the int representing the theme selected from shared preferences
        switch (Integer.valueOf(sp.getString(getString(R.string.colorThemeListPrefStr), Settings.DEFAULT_COLOR_THEME_INDEX))) {
        case 0:
            super.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Light);
            break;
        case 1:
            super.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Black);
            break;
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // ...
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // ...
        // store the current theme int
        Settings.currentTheme = Integer.valueOf(sp.getString(getString(R.string.colorThemeListPrefStr), Settings.DEFAULT_COLOR_THEME_INDEX));
        // ...
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.inputSettingsButton:
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class), Settings.PREFERENCES_REQUEST_CODE);
            break;
        // ...
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case Settings.PREFERENCES_REQUEST_CODE:
            // check if the new and old themes are different
            if (Settings.currentTheme != Integer.valueOf(sp.getString(getString(R.string.colorThemeListPrefStr), Settings.DEFAULT_COLOR_THEME_INDEX))) {
                this.finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            }
            break;
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should restart your `Application` using this simple one line of code that comes with the `support library`.

```
startActivity(IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(getActivity().getComponentName()));
```